# Why is the destructor called more than the constructor?

Tags: c++, destructor

In the following code, the destructor is called twice, while the constructor is called only once:

```
enum TFoo
{
    VAL1,
    VAL2
};

class CFoo
{

public:
    TFoo mf;

    CFoo()
    {
        cout<<"hi c'tor1\n";
        //mf = f;
    }
    CFoo(TFoo f)
    {
        cout<<"hi c'tor2\n";
        mf = f;
    }
    CFoo(TFoo &f)
    {
        cout<<"hi c'tor3\n";
        mf = f;
    }
    ~CFoo()
    {
        cout<<"bye\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<CFoo> v;
    //v.assign(1, VAL1);
    v.push_back(VAL1);
}
```

The code outputs:

> ```
> hi c'tor2
> bye
> bye
> ```

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960619/two-calls-to-destructor), which mentioned copy constructors, so I added them, but with the same result. Uncommenting the line `//v.assign(1, VAL1);` also doesn't change anything.

Comment: you miss the copy constructor `CFoo(const CFoo&)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is initially constructing using the implicit conversion operator between `TFoo` and `CFoo`, `CFoo(TFoo f)`, and then using that temporary object to pass it to `push_back` to construct the object in the container using the default copy constructor or move constructor, depending on whether you are using C++11 (which is not displaying anything). Then the temporary is destroyed and finally the object in the container (with the container itself).

You can see it [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ea1152aab3c0c06) or [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3786d83356c2b639) (C++11) even better.