# I have written one simple vector program in which i am getting following output. Can you help me to understand it's output?

Tags: c++, stl

Following is the code snippet with output.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class VectDemo
{
   public:
      VectDemo()
      {
         cout<<"Contructor"<<endl;
      }
      ~VectDemo()
      {
         cout<<"Destructor"<<endl;
      }
};
int main()
{
   vector<VectDemo> VectOfObj;
   cout<<"Size = "<<VectOfObj.size()<<endl;
   for(int i= 0;i<2;i++)
   {
      VectOfObj.push_back(VectDemo());
   }
   cout<<"Size = "<<VectOfObj.size()<<endl;
   cout<<"Capacity = "<<VectOfObj.capacity()<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Output:
Size = 0

Contructor

Destructor

Contructor

Destructor

Destructor

Size = 2

Capacity = 2

Destructor

Destructor

Comment: Please ask a specific question. What exactly do you not understand in the output? See [ask]. Try to add an explanation of your thoughts so far.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your program?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the destructor called more than the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747956/why-is-the-destructor-called-more-than-the-constructor)

Answer (score 4):

Your constructor and destructor log messages are unbalanced because `VectDemo` is not logging its copy constructor being called. `VectOfObj.push_back(VectDemo())` creates a temporary `VectDemo` object that has to then be copied into the vector. Also, a vector's elements are copied when its `capacity` grows. You are not logging when the copies are constructed, only when they are destructed.

Try this:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

char nextID = 'A';

class VectDemo
{
public:
    char id;

    VectDemo()
    {
        id = nextID++;
        cout<<"Default Constructor "<<id<<endl;
    }
    VectDemo(const VectDemo &src)
    {
        id = nextID++;
        cout<<"Copy Constructor "<<src.id<<"->"<<id<<endl;
    }
    ~VectDemo()
    {
        cout<<"Destructor "<<id<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<VectDemo> VectOfObj;
    cout<<"Before Loop"<<endl;
    cout<<"Size = "<<VectOfObj.size()<<" Capacity = "<<VectOfObj.capacity()<<endl;
    cout<<"Entering Loop"<<endl;
    for(int i= 1;i<=2;i++)
    {
        cout<<"push_back #"<<i<<endl;
        VectOfObj.push_back(VectDemo());
    }
    cout<<"After Loop"<<endl;
    cout<<"Size = "<<VectOfObj.size()<<" Capacity = "<<VectOfObj.capacity()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Before Loop
Size = 0 Capacity = 0
Entering Loop
push_back #1
Default Constructor A // temp created
Copy Constructor A->B // VectOfObj[0] created from temp
Destructor A          // temp destroyed
push_back #2
Default Constructor C // temp created
Copy Constructor C->D // VectOfObj[1] created from temp
Copy Constructor B->E // new VectOfObj[0] created from old VectOfObj[0]
Destructor B          // old VectOfObj[0] destroyed
Destructor C          // temp destroyed
After Loop
Size = 2 Capacity = 2
Destructor E          // VectOfObj[1] destroyed
Destructor D          // VectOfObj[0] destroyed
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/r6BU9p)

If you are using C++11 or later, adding a move constructor changes things a bit:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

char nextID = 'A';

class VectDemo
{
public:
    char id;

    VectDemo()
    {
        id = nextID++;
        cout<<"Default Constructor "<<id<<endl;
    }
    VectDemo(const VectDemo &src)
    {
        id = nextID++;
        cout<<"Copy Constructor "<<src.id<<"->"<<id<<endl;
    }
    VectDemo(VectDemo &&src)
    {
        id = nextID++;
        cout<<"Move Constructor "<<src.id<<"->"<<id<<endl;
    }
    ~VectDemo()
    {
        cout<<"Destructor "<<id<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<VectDemo> VectOfObj;
    cout<<"Before Loop"<<endl;
    cout<<"Size = "<<VectOfObj.size()<<" Capacity = "<<VectOfObj.capacity()<<endl;
    cout<<"Entering Loop"<<endl;
    for(int i= 1;i<=2;i++)
    {
        cout<<"push_back #"<<i<<endl;
        VectOfObj.push_back(VectDemo());
    }
    cout<<"After Loop"<<endl;
    cout<<"Size = "<<VectOfObj.size()<<" Capacity = "<<VectOfObj.capacity()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Before Loop
Size = 0 Capacity = 0
Entering Loop
push_back #1
Default Constructor A // temp created
Move Constructor A->B // VectOfObj[0] created from temp
Destructor A          // temp destroyed
push_back #2
Default Constructor C // temp created
Move Constructor C->D // VectOfObj[1] created from temp
Copy Constructor B->E // new VectOfObj[0] created from old VectOfObj[0]
Destructor B          // old VectOfObj[0] destroyed
Destructor C          // temp destroyed
After Loop
Size = 2 Capacity = 2
Destructor E          // VectOfObj[1] destroyed
Destructor D          // VectOfObj[0] destroyed
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/e8XlJr)

And, as @walnut mentioned, if you mark the move constructor as `noexcept`, the compiler can further optimize a `push_back()` that grows the vector's `capacity`, and the output changes slightly:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

char nextID = 'A';

class VectDemo
{
public:
    char id;

    VectDemo()
    {
        id = nextID++;
        cout<<"Default Constructor "<<id<<endl;
    }
    VectDemo(const VectDemo &src)
    {
        id = nextID++;
        cout<<"Copy Constructor "<<src.id<<"->"<<id<<endl;
    }
    VectDemo(VectDemo &&src) noexcept
    {
        id = nextID++;
        cout<<"Move Constructor "<<src.id<<"->"<<id<<endl;
    }
    ~VectDemo()
    {
        cout<<"Destructor "<<id<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<VectDemo> VectOfObj;
    cout<<"Before Loop"<<endl;
    cout<<"Size = "<<VectOfObj.size()<<" Capacity = "<<VectOfObj.capacity()<<endl;
    cout<<"Entering Loop"<<endl;
    for(int i= 1;i<=2;i++)
    {
        cout<<"push_back #"<<i<<endl;
        VectOfObj.push_back(VectDemo());
    }
    cout<<"After Loop"<<endl;
    cout<<"Size = "<<VectOfObj.size()<<" Capacity = "<<VectOfObj.capacity()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Before Loop
Size = 0 Capacity = 0
Entering Loop
push_back #1
Default Constructor A // temp created
Move Constructor A->B // VectOfObj[0] created from temp
Destructor A          // temp destroyed
push_back #2
Default Constructor C // temp created
Move Constructor C->D // VectOfObj[1] created from temp
Move Constructor B->E // new VectOfObj[0] created from old VectOfObj[0]
Destructor B          // old VectOfObj[0] destroyed
Destructor C          // temp destroyed
After Loop
Size = 2 Capacity = 2
Destructor E          // VectOfObj[1] destroyed
Destructor D          // VectOfObj[0] destroyed
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/SO7NGC)

Comment: And if you make the move constructor `noexcept`, then it will also be used for the `B->E` relocation.